# Pug компиляция в HTML. На выходе красивый HTML

Tags: html, gulp, pug

Есть код pug

```
ul.header__menu-list#header-menu
   li.header__menu-item
      a.header__menu-link(href='catalog.html') Ювелирные изделия       
   li.header__menu-item
      a.header__menu-link(href='') Часы
   li.header__menu-item
      a.header__menu-link(href='') Ручки
   li.header__menu-item
      a.header__menu-link(href='') Аксессуары
   li.header__menu-item
      a.header__menu-link(href='') Новости
   li.header__menu-item
      a.header__menu-link(href='contacts.html') Контакты
```

И получается:

```
<ul class="header__menu-list" id="header-menu">
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="catalog.html">Ювелирные изделия</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Часы</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Ручки</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Аксессуары</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Новости</a></li>
    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="contacts.html">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

Есть ли опция в gulp-pug или же какой-то форматтер для HTML, чтобы он вставлял в HTML перенос строки после каждой строки.
Вот так:

```
<ul class="header__menu-list" id="header-menu">

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="catalog.html">Ювелирные изделия</a></li>

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Часы</a></li>

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Ручки</a></li>

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Аксессуары</a></li>

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="">Новости</a></li>

    <li class="header__menu-item"><a class="header__menu-link" href="contacts.html">Контакты</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: но зачем это нужно?

Comment: Для начальника, он не понимает pug и не может смотреть на HTML без переноса строки.
А я не хочу писать на чистом HTML, я привык к pug.